# How to use a foreach loop to generate a textbox to show a list of questions in C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, dynamically-generated

I'm new to windows forms.

My program is to show random questions for the user to answer and I want when the user press the end button to show the questions and the user answers and the right answer should my `question` and `answers` be in `var`?

I created a string list and can't seem to figure it out.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication7
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int numofquestionleft;
        int answer;
        int useranswer33;
        Timer Clock = new Timer();
        List<string> questions = new List<string>();
        List<string> answers = new List<string>();
        List<string> useranswers= new List<string>();

        
        public Form1(){
        }


        int[] Rand(int v)
        {//random number generater

            Random r = new Random();
        int a = r.Next(1,v);
            int b = r.Next(1,v);
            int[] N = {Math.Max(a,b) , Math.Min(a,b)};
            return N;
        
        }
        void generate()
        {
            //user choosing the range of numbers that is used in questions
            int range = 0;
            switch (rangebox1.SelectedIndex)
            { 
                case 0:
                    range = 100;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    range = 500;
                        break;
                case 2:
                    range = 1000;
                        break;
                default:
                    MessageBox.Show("Put a range !");
                    break;
            
            }
            int[] numbers = Rand(range);           
            switch (Operationbox1.SelectedIndex)
            { 
                case 0:
                    questionlbl1.Text = string.Format("{0} + {1} =",numbers[0],numbers[1]);
                     answer = numbers[0] + numbers[1];
                    answers.Add(answer.ToString());
                    break;
                case 1:
                    questionlbl1.Text = string.Format("{0} - {1} =" , numbers[0], numbers[1]);
                     answer = numbers[0] - numbers[1];
                    answers.Add(answer.ToString());
                    break;
                case 2:
                    questionlbl1.Text = string.Format("{0} * {1} =" , numbers[0], numbers[1]);
                    answer = numbers[0] * numbers[1];
                    answers.Add(answer.ToString());
                    break;
                case 3:
                    questionlbl1.Text = string.Format("{0} / {1} =" , numbers[0], numbers[1]);
                     answer = numbers[0] / numbers[1];
                    answers.Add(answer.ToString());
                    break;
                default:
                    MessageBox.Show("Please insert a operation");
                    break;   
            }
        \
        }
        void numberquest()
        {//if the number of question left is more than 0 genrate and minues 1 question

            if (numofquestionleft > 0)
            {
                generate();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("End of questions, Please press END");
            }
            numofquestionleft--;
            
            numberofquestionnumber.Text = "Questions left " + numofquestionleft;        
        }

        private void genbutton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { //Button that start the timer and generate the question
            numofquestionleft = Convert.ToInt32(numofquest1.Text);
            generate();  
        }

        private void end22_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var questionlist in question)
            {
               // here is my problem what should I put here to display the question list 
               
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {//button that checks if the useranswer is right or wrong
             useranswer33 = Convert.ToInt32(useranswerbox1.Text);
            useranswers.Add(answer.ToString());
            if (useranswer33 == answer)
            {
                result.Text = "Your answer is correct";
            }
            else
            {
                result.Text = "Your answer is Wrong, The correct answer;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to show all questions in a textbox? What datatype is _questions_?

Comment: i want to show all the questions that the user had been asked in the quiz, List<string> questions = new List<string>(); this is the datatype i don't know if this is what you meant if not should i put my whole code here?

Answer (score 0):

You can do such thing to dynamically generate controls to create your quiz:

```
var questions = new string[]
{ 
  "This is the question 1",
  "This is the question 2",
  "This is the question 3",
  "This is the question 4"
}
int x = 50;
int y = 10;
int dy = 30;
int width = 250;
foreach ( var question in questions )
{
  var textbox = new TextBox();
  textbox.Text = question;
  textbox.Width = width;
  textbox.Location = new Point(x, y);
  Controls.Add(textbox);
  y += dy;
}
```

You can adapt for what you want by changing and adding controls for you need: type of controls, appearance, locations, sizes, content, and so on.

Here controls are added to the form itself but you can put them in a panel or any container:

```
SomePanel.Controls.Add(textbox);
```

Hence you can create questions with labels and add a textbox or radioboxes for answers and name them. You can also keep controls created to get answers later:

```
var texboxesAnswers = new List<TextBox>()
int index = 0;
// ...
foreach ( var question in questions )
{
  var label = new Label();
  label.Text = question;
  label.AutoSize = true;
  label.Location = new Point(x, y);
  PanelQuestions.Controls.Add(label);
  y += dy;
  var textbox = new TextBox();
  textbox.Text = "";
  textbox.Width = width;
  textbox.Location = new Point(x, y);
  textbox.Name = "TextBoxAnswer" + (index++);
  PanelQuestions.Controls.Add(textbox);
  texboxesAnswers.Add(textbox);
  y += dy + dy / 2;
}
```

Without using `textboxesAnswers` you can get all answers like that:

```
using System.Linq;

var textboxesAnswers = PanelQuestions.Controls
                       .OfType<TextBox>()
                       .Where(n => n.Name.StartsWith("TextBoxAnswer"));
```

Comment: Thanks for helping in the editing man, but i put my code can you check it please, thanks

Comment: What do you think about dynamic generation of labels for questions and textboxes for answers?

Comment: at the end I managed to make it work but I want to ask you a question is there a way to place to lists next to each other in foreach?